# RestTemplate Spring is not showing in android

Tags: android, spring

I'm trying to make my application get some data from a WebApi, so I added 
`compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.0.M3'`
to my Gradle and Sync with the project, but when I tried to declare my `RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();`, it just show that it cannot resolve the symbol "RestTemplate" and there's no error message at all but this. Have I done something wrong? Anyone knows why is that happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add the following to build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M3'
}repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone'
    }
}
```

also you can follow [official docs](http://projects.spring.io/spring-android/) here

Comment: If anyone's still using this, the new url for the repo seems to be https://repo.spring.io/artifactory/libs-milestone-local

Comment: @StefanNorberg My gratitude to you. Thank You very much for posting this comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one:

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.android', name: 'spring-android-rest-template', version: '1.0.1.RELEASE
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a more complete answer, the following code is the one I'm using:

```
android { 
    // Default code...

    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }
}
dependencies {
    // Default code...
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M3'
}
```